# Use date to determine when *Newly Posted* status should expire

Tags: php, css

I have a comics website, http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/, which I add new comics to each week. I'd like a newly posted comic to remain highlighted until 3 days after the post date.

So, here's before:

[image]

Here's desired:

[image]

I'm considering the following logic:

date in the database is currently set to datetime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

**PHP:** Get date of comic with a date = $row['date'] url parameter:

```
        echo '<ul>';
            $imageCounter = 0;
            while ($imageCounter < $imagesPerPage && ($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc())) {                  
                echo '<li>';
                    echo    '<span class="comics"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'">
                            <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?date='. $row['date'] . '&img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a> 
                            <br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . '</span>';                               
                echo '</li>';
                $imageCounter++;
            }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Then set datetime to that date...

```
$datetime1 = date_create($_GET['date']);
```

Now, I'd like to somehow set `datetime2 = (datetime1 + 3 days)`...

Then compare...

```
if ($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
   set "comics" span class in CSS file to something else that would somehow highlight the newest post...
}
else {
   set "comics" span class in CSS file to default
}
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT--------------------------------

I'm trying this now to highlight the newest comic for a period of 3 days... unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out how to highlight just the latest comic instead of all of the comics if the condition is met.

```
    //GET date  
        $desc = (isset($_GET['description']) ? ($_GET['description']) : null);  


    $row = $catResult->fetch_assoc();

    $current_date = new DateTime;
    echo "Current Date: " . $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo "<br />";

    $comic_date = new DateTime($row['date']);
    echo "Comic Date: " . $comic_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $comic_date->modify('3 day');


    //DISPLAY IMAGES TO CORRECT PAGE FROM DATABASE  
    echo '<ul>';
        $imageCounter = 0;
        while (($row['date'] < $current_date) && ($imageCounter < $imagesPerPage) && ($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc())) {
                echo '<li>';                
                    echo    '<span class="comics"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'">
                                <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a> 
                                <br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . $row['date'] . '</span>';                                
                    $imageCounter++;
                echo '</li>';

            }   

        if ($row['date'] >= $current_date) {
                echo '<li>';                
                    echo    '<span class="newcomics"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'">
                                <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a> 
                                <br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . $row['date'] . '</span>';                                
                    $imageCounter++;
                echo '</li>';
            }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I think it's too much process there. what you need is a cron job that checks a flag (like: is_new) in the database and switches the value between 1 and 0.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I'd still need to compare dates somehow, right?

Comment: sure, but I was suggesting that's why it's a comment not an answer :) this way you can just compare the date of today - comic creating date and check if the answer is greater than three days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to compare dates with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Example how to modify and compare dates:

```
# PHP >= 5.4
$row['date'] = '2013-01-03 16:15:14';
$d = (new DateTime($row['date']))->modify('3 day');
echo $d >= (new DateTime) ? 'NEW' : 'OLD';

# PHP < 5.4
$row['date'] = '2013-01-03 16:15:14';
$n = new DateTime;
$d = new DateTime($row['date']);
$d->modify('3 day');
echo $d >= $n ? 'NEW' : 'OLD';
```

## OR

You can do this with sql statement:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    t.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS is_new
FROM 
    someTable AS t
```

Comment: It's more efficient to subtract 3 days from `NOW()` than to add 3 days to the `date` column, since a condition like `date >= ...` can make use of an index whereas `DATE_ADD(date, ...) >= ...` can't (or, rather, MySQL isn't smart enough to do that).

Comment: @Glavic how can I single out the comic that I want to highlight? If you look above, my code iterates through all comics from the database... see above code edit

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: updated my answer. @Growler: put your `$comic_date` logic in the `while` loop.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I feel like my updated answer should be working... but if you see EDIT 2, the comic date and current date are echoing out to be the same... yet they aren't. Why?

Comment: @Growler: What do you get if you print out `$row['date']` directly? Or even do `var_export($row)`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen nevermind fixed that problem. It's outputting all comics with date < current_date... but, It's not outputting the comic with date > current_date even though I have an if check. See updated code.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen can I just use echo  ($row['date'] >= $current_date) ? '<span class="newcomics">' : '<span class="comics">... ? I thought so, but that's not outputting the latest comic with date >= $current_date.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen just lemme know if you can still help. Thank you :)

Comment: @Growler: Honestly, this question has become so confusing that I no longer have any idea what your actual code looks like or why it might not work. The code you have pasted above obviously won't work, since you're only using the first row to set `$comic_date` and then only using the _other_ rows to actually output anything. But that has been pointed out to you already by Glavić above, and from your comments it seems you're doing something else now.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen okay, I also think it has become way too confusing. I'll try to work on simplifying it then repost when I've worked it on some more. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

"Now, I'd like to somehow set datetime2 = (datetime1 + 3 days)..."

Use `strtotime()` to turn the date into seconds. Then you can play around with it how you like.

For example:

```
$expiry_date = strtotime($time_stamp) + 259200; // 259200 = 3 days in seconds
```

Then check the date like this:

```
if($expiry_date < date("Y-m-d", time()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I'd like to note that it's also possible to do this in the SQL query, e.g. like this:

```sql
SELECT *, (date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) AS is_new
FROM comics
ORDER BY date DESC
```

([demo on SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/50He0c1D2y))

Comment: @Growler: You know, it might help if you described your "trouble" a bit.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code above. I wasn't able to get yours to work, so I tried Glavic's idea above (php datetime).

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to just save the posted date on the db and then move the calculation all on client side, with some javascript code.
You can expose the posted date to the javascritpt client side by setting an attribute like data-posted="....".

Comment: I don't see the point in using Javascript in this simple case. Everything that's needed is small CSS code to add borders. And the `easier` way is prefered..

Comment: @barius yes you are right, I just say to use javascript for the calcculation not for the rendering. Of course css is the way to go for rendering the highlight. I suggest to use js instead of server side job or similar.